# Finding All Connected Components of an Undirected Graph

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have a list of objects (undirected edges) like below:

```
pairs = [

 pair:["a2", "a5"],
 pair:["a3", "a6"],
 pair:["a4", "a5"],
 pair:["a7", "a9"]

];
```

I need to find **all** components (connected nodes) in separate groups. So from given pairs I need to get:

```
groups = [
  group1: ["a2", "a5", "a4"],
  group2: ["a3", "a6"],
  group3: ["a7", "a9"]
];
```

I actually read some answers on here and googled this and that's how I learned this is called "finding connected components in a graph" but, could't find any **sample code**. I use JavaScript on Node.js but any sample with other languages would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be solved using a **Breadth First Search**.

The idea is to traverse all reachable vertices from a source vertex, by hopping to adjacent vertices. Vertices right next to the source vertex are first visited, followed by vertices that are 2 hops away, etc.

The code here is not very efficient due to the graph representation used, which is an **edge list** . To obtain better performance, you might want to use an **adjacency list**.

Here's some working code in JavaScript. I used `node.js` to run this:

```
// Breadth First Search function
// v is the source vertex
// all_pairs is the input array, which contains length 2 arrays
// visited is a dictionary for keeping track of whether a node is visited
var bfs = function(v, all_pairs, visited) {
  var q = [];
  var current_group = [];
  var i, nextVertex, pair;
  var length_all_pairs = all_pairs.length;
  q.push(v);
  while (q.length > 0) {
    v = q.shift();
    if (!visited[v]) {
      visited[v] = true;
      current_group.push(v);
      // go through the input array to find vertices that are
      // directly adjacent to the current vertex, and put them
      // onto the queue
      for (i = 0; i < length_all_pairs; i += 1) {
        pair = all_pairs[i];
        if (pair[0] === v && !visited[pair[1]]) {
          q.push(pair[1]);
        } else if (pair[1] === v && !visited[pair[0]]) {
          q.push(pair[0]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // return everything in the current "group"
  return current_group;
};

var pairs = [
  ["a2", "a5"],
  ["a3", "a6"],
  ["a4", "a5"],
  ["a7", "a9"]
];

var groups = [];
var i, k, length, u, v, src, current_pair;
var visited = {};

// main loop - find any unvisited vertex from the input array and
// treat it as the source, then perform a breadth first search from
// it. All vertices visited from this search belong to the same group
for (i = 0, length = pairs.length; i < length; i += 1) {
  current_pair = pairs[i];
  u = current_pair[0];
  v = current_pair[1];
  src = null;
  if (!visited[u]) {
    src = u;
  } else if (!visited[v]) {
    src = v;
  }
  if (src) {
    // there is an unvisited vertex in this pair.
    // perform a breadth first search, and push the resulting
    // group onto the list of all groups
    groups.push(bfs(src, pairs, visited));
  }
}

// show groups
console.log(groups);
```

**UPDATE**: I have updated my answer to demonstrate how to convert an edge list to an adjacency list. The code is commented and should illustrate the concept rather well. The Breadth First Search function is modified to make use of an adjacency list, along with another slight modification (regarding marking vertices as visited).

```
// Converts an edgelist to an adjacency list representation
// In this program, we use a dictionary as an adjacency list,
// where each key is a vertex, and each value is a list of all
// vertices adjacent to that vertex
var convert_edgelist_to_adjlist = function(edgelist) {
  var adjlist = {};
  var i, len, pair, u, v;
  for (i = 0, len = edgelist.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    pair = edgelist[i];
    u = pair[0];
    v = pair[1];
    if (adjlist[u]) {
      // append vertex v to edgelist of vertex u
      adjlist[u].push(v);
    } else {
      // vertex u is not in adjlist, create new adjacency list for it
      adjlist[u] = [v];
    }
    if (adjlist[v]) {
      adjlist[v].push(u);
    } else {
      adjlist[v] = [u];
    }
  }
  return adjlist;
};

// Breadth First Search using adjacency list
var bfs = function(v, adjlist, visited) {
  var q = [];
  var current_group = [];
  var i, len, adjV, nextVertex;
  q.push(v);
  visited[v] = true;
  while (q.length > 0) {
    v = q.shift();
    current_group.push(v);
    // Go through adjacency list of vertex v, and push any unvisited
    // vertex onto the queue.
    // This is more efficient than our earlier approach of going
    // through an edge list.
    adjV = adjlist[v];
    for (i = 0, len = adjV.length; i < len; i += 1) {
      nextVertex = adjV[i];
      if (!visited[nextVertex]) {
        q.push(nextVertex);
        visited[nextVertex] = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return current_group;
};

var pairs = [
  ["a2", "a5"],
  ["a3", "a6"],
  ["a4", "a5"],
  ["a7", "a9"]
];

var groups = [];
var visited = {};
var v;

// this should look like:
// {
//   "a2": ["a5"],
//   "a3": ["a6"],
//   "a4": ["a5"],
//   "a5": ["a2", "a4"],
//   "a6": ["a3"],
//   "a7": ["a9"],
//   "a9": ["a7"]
// }
var adjlist = convert_edgelist_to_adjlist(pairs);

for (v in adjlist) {
  if (adjlist.hasOwnProperty(v) && !visited[v]) {
    groups.push(bfs(v, adjlist, visited));
  }
}

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Nice, I actually agree that BFS has the potential to get a bit more optimal in solving the problem, than what I propose if written optimally. My algorithm is meant to easily handle dynamically adding new ribs, which seems not to be the case of the OP. You get +1 from me.

Comment: @yanhan I'm not familiar with the graph algorithms. Can you open using adjacency list? Is it gonna require changing bfs function too? Thanks!

Comment: @user3211198 the conversion from edge list to adjacency list is actually quite simple, and yes it will require changing the bfs function slightly. I will only be free some time later, and will update this answer with a new section on it.

Comment: your ```convert_edgelist_to_adjlist``` function should return groups with empty arrays and not just an empty object though in the event the group has no connections. So if you have A connected to B with a single connection, then the adjacency list should be ```{ A: [], B: []}```. Currently it returns an empty object doesn't solve for this case. Easy to fix on my end, but you may want to update the answer to accommodate that case.

Answer (score 5):

The task you want to solve is best sovled with the algorithm of [Disjoint Set Forest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests).

Basically it is meant to solve exactly the problem you describe in an optimal manner.

- assign every vertex the set of vertices in which it belong. Let us denote it as `root(v)`. Every such set will be considered as planted tree throughout the whole algorithm. Thus we will associate the `root(v)` with the root of the tree. So let's assume `root(v)` returns a vertex index.
- The algorithm will go easiest if you keep throughout the algorithm one auxiliary array - the parent vertex of each vertex in its planted tree. If no such vertex exists we will store -1 instead to denote that. Thus you start the algorithm with `parent[v] = -1` for each `v` as all vertices are initially in their own trees and you have no parents
- We will also need one additional array that stores something that is called the rank of a vertex. It is basically equal to the depth of the subtree having the vertex as root. You need not worry too much about it. The array is used for performance optimizations. Let's name it `rank`. We initialize all ranks to 1s
- You start processing the edges one by one and each edge might possibly trigger merge of trees. That is the interesting part in which you can optimise.

Here is a pseudo code:

```
parent[v] = -1 for v in Vertices
rank[v] = 1 for v in Vertices
root (v):
   processed = []
   while parent[v] != -1
      processed << v
      v = parent[v]
   for vertex : processed
      parent = v // optimisation: here we move the assoc. trees to be directly connected the root
   return v

join (v1, v2):
  if rank[v1] < rank[v2]:
     parent[v1] = v2
  if rank[v1] > rank[v2]:
     parent[v2] = v1
  parent[v2] = v1
  rank[v1]++
   
merge_trees (v1, v2)
  root1 = root(v1)
  root2 = root(v2)
  if root1 == root2:
    // already in same tree nothing else to be done here
    return true
  else
    // join trees
    join (v1, v2)
    return false

main:
   numberTrees = size(Vertives)
   for edge: edges
      if merge_trees(edge.begin, edge.end):
         numberTrees--
   print numberTrees // this is the number you are interested in.
```

**NOTE** If you are not interested too much in performance you can omit the rank thing. Without it your algorithm might run slower, but maybe it will be easier for you to understand and maintain. In this scenario you can `join` vertices in any direction. I should warn you that then there will exist scenarios that will trigger your algorithm to run slower.

Answer (score 4):

You want to do [Graph Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal)

In your *specific* example, you have no # of nodes, and it may even be difficult to traverse the graph so first we'll get a "graph"

```
// It will return an object like Vertices{node: EdgesTo{node,node}, node:...}
function toGraph(arr) {
    var graph = {}; // this will hold the node "IDs"
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // "create node" if the it's not added in the graph yet
        graph[arr[i][0]] = graph[arr[i][0]] || {};
        graph[arr[i][1]] = graph[arr[i][1]] || {};
        // add bidirectional "edges" to the "vertices"
        // Yes, we set the value to null, but what's important is to add the key.
        graph[arr[i][0]][arr[i][1]] = null;
        graph[arr[i][1]][arr[i][0]] = null;
    }
    return graph;
}
```

Then it is very easy to traverse the graph using any method that you choose ([DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search))

I will make an example using DFS:

```
// to be called after getting the result from toGraph(arr)
function getSubGraphs(graph) {
    var subGraphs = []; // array of connected vertices
    var visited = {};
    for (var i in graph) { // for every node...
        var subGraph = dfs(graph, i, visited); // ... we call dfs
        if (subGraph != null) // if vertex is not added yet in another graph
        subGraphs.push(subGraph);
    }
    return subGraphs;
}

// it will return an array of all connected nodes in a subgraph
function dfs(graph, node, visited) {
    if (visited[node]) return null; // node is already visited, get out of here.
    var subGraph = [];
    visited[node] = true;
    subGraph.push(node);
    for (var i in graph[node]) {
        var result = dfs(graph, i, visited);
        if (result == null) continue;
        subGraph = subGraph.concat(result);
    }
    return subGraph;
}
```

And you would end up calling it like `getSubGraphs(toGraph(myArray));` and do whatever you need with that.

[**<kbd>Fiddle Here</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/xYrgN/)

Comment: Does toGraph convert an edge list to adjacency list? Do you think this way is more efficient than the answer I selected? Thanks!

Comment: @user3211198 BFS and DFS are same from performance perspective. This answer shows another algorithm and displays how to construct the adjecency list from what you have.

Comment: @user3211198 Yes, it converts it to an adjacency list which is "easier" to read for us. As Boris said, they have the similar performance. IMO DFS is easier to implement, but in this case... it is recursive, so a dense graph or deep tree may cause your program to crash. You may need to implement an iterative DFS to avoid that.

Comment: @Goodwine Thanks, not only I got my answer but I learned a lot thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic solution for any length of at least pairs of connected parts. The above example is in the view of this solution groups of pairs, because the index of the nested array is another given group.

To get a result, all connected items are normalized to tupels/pairs, in this case to the value and the outer index value.

Then grouped by tupels and returned as grouped items without indices.

The main grouping algorithm works with iterating iterating all tupels and all groups.

```js
const
    addIfNotExist = (array, value) => array.includes(value) || array.push(value),
    groupConnectedValues = (groups, tupel) => {
        const objects = [];
        let first;
        for (const group of groups) {
            if (!tupel.some((v, i) => group[i].includes(v))) {
                objects.push(group);
                continue;
            }
            if (!first) objects.push(first = group);
            group.forEach((items, i) => items.forEach(addIfNotExist.bind(null, first[i])));
        }

        if (first) tupel.forEach((v, i) => addIfNotExist(first[i], v));
        else objects.push(tupel.map(v => [v]));

        return objects;
    },
    data = [["a2", "a5"], ["a3", "a6"], ["a4", "a5"], ["a7", "a9"]],
    result = data
        .flatMap((a, i) => a.map(v => [v, i]))
        .reduce(groupConnectedValues, [])
        .map(([a]) => a);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```