# Javascript group array by intersection

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Given an array of paired integers, HOW can I group by intersections. Does anyone have a simple function that could convert my input, into the desired output?

Input

```
var in = ["0:3", "1:3", "4:5", "5:6", "6:8"]
```

Desired output

```
[
    [0, 1, 3],
    [4, 5, 6, 8]
]
```

UPDATE:

@apsiller asked my question in the comments more clearly then I originally posted:

"Considering each number as a node in a graph, and each pairing `x:y` as an edge between nodes `x` and `y`, find the sets of numbers that can be traveled to using the edges defined. That is, in graph theory terms, find the distinct [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) within such a graph.

For instance, there is no way to travel from 4 to 0 so they are in different groups, but there is a way to travel from 1 to 0 (by way of 3) so they are in the same group."

To reiterate the desired output is a grouping of transversable nodes, based on a potentially random input set.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: do you have tried something? what happens with `7`?

Comment: Nothing working yet. Don't think about this as a list of integers, they could be strings. Given the working array, I am trying to find the intersections / overlap that exists. 7 should be irrelevant.

Comment: Not sure what "intersections" means? What is the algorithm used to derive expected result from input?

Comment: @guest271314 What the OP wants is "considering each number as a node in a graph, and each pairing `x:y` as an edge between nodes `x` and `y`, find the sets of numbers that can be traveled to using the edges defined." For instance, there is no way to travel from `4` to `0` so they are in different groups, but there is a way to travel from `1` to `0` (by way of `3`) so they are in the same group.

Comment: @apsillers Yes exactly.

Comment: basically a duplicate of [Find connected components in a graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078445/find-connected-components-in-a-graph) but specifically for JavaScript code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone. Given everyones input I was able to find a similar question on here that led me my answer. [Finding All Connected Components of an Undirected Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900713/finding-all-connected-components-of-an-undirected-graph)

The first step was to change my input to groups of pairs.

```
var input = [
    [0, 3],
    [1, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [5, 6],
    [6, 8]
]
```

The next step was to use whats called **Breadth-first search**

```
function breadthFirstSearch(node, nodes, visited) {
    var queue = [];
    var group = [];
    var pair  = null;
    queue.push(node);
    while (queue.length > 0) {
        node = queue.shift();
        if (!visited[node]) {
            visited[node] = true;
            group.push(node);
            for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
                pair = nodes[i];
                if (pair[0] === node && !visited[pair[1]]) {
                    queue.push(pair[1]);
                } else if (pair[1] === node && !visited[pair[0]]) {
                    queue.push(pair[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return group;
};
```

---

```
function groupReachableVertices(input) {
    var groups  = [];
    var visited = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        var current_pair = input[i];
        var u = current_pair[0];
        var v = current_pair[1];
        var src = null;
        if (!visited[u]) {
            src = u;
        } else if (!visited[v]) {
            src = v;
        }
        if (src) {
            groups.push(breadthFirstSearch(src, input, visited));
        }
    }
    return groups;
};
```

---

Putting it all together...

```
var output = groupReachableVertices(input);
[
    [0, 1, 3],
    [4, 5, 6, 8]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```js
function group(data) {
  var r = [[]],c = 0,a = [0]
  var d = data.map(e => e.split(':').sort((a, b) => a - b)).sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
  
  d.forEach(function(e, i) {
    if (e[0] > a[a.length - 1]) {
      r.push(e)
      a.push(e[1])
      c++
    } else {
      r[c] = r[c].concat(e)
      a[a.length - 1] = e[1]
    }
  })
  return r.map(e => [...new Set(e)].sort((a, b) => a - b))
}

var test1 = ["0:3", "1:3", "4:5", "5:6", "6:8"]
var test2 = ["0:3", "1:3", "4:5", "9:11", "10:12", '3:6', "7:8"]
var test3 = ["20:15", "4:0", "1:3", "5:1", "9:11", "10:12", '3:6', "8:7"]

console.log(JSON.stringify(group(test1)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(group(test2)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(group(test3)))
```

Comment: I guess you are calculating the disjointed unions however it might not be what's requested. For example in your second example the edge with the vertices `"4:5"` is not connected with any of the edges with vertices `"0:3"`, `"1:3"` and `"3:6"` yet listed in the same array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and collect all nodes in it. It works for any values.

```js
var data = ["0:3", "1:3", "4:5", "a:8", "5:a"],
    result = data
        .map(function (a) { return a.split(':'); })
        .reduce(function (hash) {
            return function (r, a) {
                if (hash[a[0]] && hash[a[1]]) {
                    hash[a[0]].push.apply(hash[a[0]], r.splice(r.indexOf(hash[a[1]]), 1)[0]);
                    hash[a[1]] = hash[a[0]];
                    return r;
                }
                if (hash[a[0]]) {
                    hash[a[1]] = hash[a[0]];
                    hash[a[1]].push(a[1]);
                    return r;
                }
                if (hash[a[1]]) {
                    hash[a[0]] = hash[a[1]];
                    hash[a[0]].push(a[0]);
                    return r;
                }
                hash[a[0]] = a.slice();
                hash[a[1]] = hash[a[0]];
                return r.concat([hash[a[0]]]);
            };
        }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, by using `Object.values()` and `Set` object you can simply do as follows in ES6.

```js
function getConnectedVertices(a){
  return [...new Set(Object.values(a.reduce((h,v) => (h[v[0]] ? h[v[1]] ? (h[v[0]] = h[v[0]].concat(h[v[1]]),
                                                                           h[v[1]] = h[v[0]])
                                                                        : (h[v[0]].push(v[1]),
                                                                           h[v[1]] = h[v[0]])
                                                              : h[v[1]] ? (h[v[1]].push(v[0]),
                                                                           h[v[0]] = h[v[1]])
                                                                        :  h[v[0]] = h[v[1]] = v,
                                            h),{})))];
}

var input = ["0:3", "1:3", "4:5", "5:6", "6:8"].map(s => s.split(":")),
   result = getConnectedVertices(input);
console.log(result);
```